# Is there a limit for a logical line in /etc/aliases with linux

Tags: linux, centos, email

I want to set up a maillist consisting of several e-mail-addresses using an alias in `/etc/aliases`.

Is there a known limitation here with regards to number of lines/chars/entries per alias?

From what I read in the manpage I can include a file containing the addresses for that alias.

I expect some hundred addresses. If this detail is important:
I am using postfix on CentOS 5 x86_64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some fairly complex /etc/aliases files on Postfix systems. The worst was 900+ lines with nested groups and references. The biggest list of recipients I had on one line was 30 or so. I haven't noticed a limit though, although there may be something hardcoded.

Comment: 900+ is pretty much - propably enough for my purposes. But you have to do "newaliases" after changing lines... So although this answers my question I will go for the include-file.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of what the upper limit of the aliases line length might be, and it probably depends on the mailer, postfix/sendmail/etc. But I'd recommend you using an include file where you have more entries than fingers, as it's much easier to manage and you can easily add/remove from the included file without having to rebuild your aliases database. There will be no issue with hundreds of lines in your file.

The format in your /etc/aliases is:

```
:include:/path/to/filename
```

Within the file, you have one email per line.

Comment: I already figured out the syntax for include. So there is no need to "newaliases" after changing the include-file? Interesting.

Comment: @Nils - correct, newaliases is only necessary when you modify the aliases file itself, any included files can be changed independently. Well at least with both sendmail and postfix. I've not used any other MTAs.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a limitation, I think it is 1024 bytes for one alias.
"newaliases" reports this but I missed it and it took me a while of confusion when I could not send mail to this particular alias.
I edit the /etc/alias file, I do not use "include". My system is FreeBSD 10.1 using sendmail.

Comment: Since I asked for CentOS - can you confirm that there, too?